# How to let the user switch language in playframework 2

Tags: scala, internationalization, playframework-2.0

In my play 1.x controller I had this:

```
public static void language(final String language){
    Lang.change(language);
    Header referer = request.headers.get("referer");
    if(referer == null){
        index();
    }else{
        redirect(referer.value());
    }
}
```

I would like to do the same in play 2.x but I have the impression that functionality is not available any more. This is what I have so far

```
  def language(language:String) = Action { implicit request =>

    // TODO change language

    val referer = request.headers.get("referer")
    referer.map{ referer =>
      Redirect(referer, FOUND);
    }getOrElse(
      Ok(views.html.index())
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaI18N#Externalizing-messages), in Play 2.4, inside the controller you can do

```
ctx().changeLang(new Lang(Lang.forCode("fr")));
```

You need to have a file conf/messages.fr so the application can refer to it for the message. You can start from the [messages.default](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/26a9c7625d6c482abf1c6ecedacff34d670bee01/framework/src/play/src/main/resources/messages.default) file and put your own messages.

Answer (score 5):

You can store the language in the user session. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/julienrf/chooze/blob/master/app/controllers/CookieLang.scala)

This question has already been [asked on the Play Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/change%2420implicit%2420lang/play-framework/8LRKHNm9D4Q/eWDjfyr4U9AJ)

Comment: in fact there is no such system so you have to implement the language cookie yourself and pass the language to the template, see this example: https://github.com/julienrf/chooze/blob/master/app/controllers/CookieLang.scala